# embedded programming in C

Tags: c++, c, embedded

I am a newbie as far as it comes to embedded systems programming. I have to write lots of simple C or C++ programs like `atoi`, `itoa`, `oct_to_dec`, etc., which would have been easy to write in normal C.

But my hardware unit does not have the usual header functions and hence I cannot use standard library functions. :(

Could someone help me with some pointers to this? Any sampler or notes also would be of great help.

Thanks!

Comment: Pointers to what?   you want source code for all those functions?  Have you started on ANY of them?  Post us some code, explain what you need help with, and we'll go from there.

Comment: OK, so you don't have access to the "usual header functions." What DO you have access to? What language are you writing in, and for what platform?

Comment: @abelenky - Pointers to "reading material" . I did not ask you for source code at all! Read my post properly!

Comment: Tell us what you are building with, and what for.

Comment: What reading material have you looked at? K&R? Deitle?  Stackoverflow is not a substitute for basic Google searches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most embedded compilers do indeed have an implementation of at least a subset of the standard C libraries, including functions like itoa and atoi. Depending on the compiler and the type of microcontroller that you are using, you might not have to rewrite any of the functions.

Seeing that this is homework, however, that might be the point.

If you give more details on the MCU and compiler that you are using, as well as a specific problem that you are having, then I could edit my answer to make it more relevant to your needs.

**General Pointers**

Writing embedded code deals much more with the microcontroller's architecture than with library functions. You probably won't be using much in the way of printf or cout, but will be doing a lot of bit shifting and writing to registers. So brush up up your bitwise operators. That said, the most important thing you can do when learning to write embedded software is to **master the architecture**. I cannot stress this enough. You will spend a **lot** of time with your data sheet, so get a jump on your class and start reading the data sheet for your microcontroller.

Also, if this is your first embedded class, you shouldn't worry about strings, because you  probably won't be using them at all. Most of your work will probably be centered around writing code to interface with hardware.

Answer (score 3):

Why would anybody in this day and age write atoi, itoa etc except as a learning exercise?
Source code for these has been freely available for decades.

http://www.uclibc.org/ is a good place to go for an embedded systems c library - much smaller than glibc. It can also be used for closed source software (Lesser GPL licensed) and the source code is available. http://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/

Answer (score 1):

look at an ascii table, look for patterns.  For instance, converting atoi consists of finding out how many characters are in a string, and then converting each character to it's digit equivalent, and then multiplying it by the correct power of 10

Comment: Yeah but to read the characters, I generally use inbuilt header function. How will we read a string without using header functions

Comment: If you are only converting a character to it's decimal equivalent you can subtract the ascii value '0' from it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple possibility is to download something like [GLibC](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/) code and then pick out the functions that you want. Just note that the code is GPL and will require you to distribute source code with the application.

Another possibility is to use the [Android](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/bionic.git;a=summary) C library although there is a bit of ARM assembler for functions like  memcpy. (Android has a more liberal licence)

Unfortunately anything that required a system call cannot be used on your system so there you are on your own.